# now() function being tempratmental

Tags: php, mysql

my now() function is tempramental sometimes it records the value in mysql sometimes it does not. Especially if i am bypassing it by entering the username and password and pressing enter rather than clicking the login button. Ive attached my code.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('config.php');

// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$input_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '".$input_username."'" );

$sql = "UPDATE user SET logindate=NOW() WHERE username='" .mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."'";
mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in SQL: " . mysql_error());  

// Check username and password match
$row = mysql_fetch_array($login);
if(mysql_num_rows($login)){
    if($row['password'] === md5($_POST['password'])){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; // store in session
    } else{
        // Invalid login
        echo header('Location: loginerror.php');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Couldn't you find a more descriptive title for your question? Couldn't you [format](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your code better?

Comment: Don't you think it's a problem that you're referencing `$_SESSION['username']` *before* you set it?

Comment: you'd better check that $_POST has been set too

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see you're putting some SQL in `$sql` and never running it. Is that how it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

You have an unclosed brace:

```
if($row['password'] === md5($_POST['password']))
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; // store in session
else
```

Fix:

```
if($row['password'] === md5($_POST['password']))
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; // store in session
}
else
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update the login time only if a match is found (and you didn't make it execute) - you're updating it whether the user exists or not!

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('config.php');

if(isset($_POST)){
    // Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
    $input_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='".$input_username."'");

    // Check username and password match
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($login);
    if(mysql_num_rows($login)){
        if($row['password'] === md5($_POST['password'])){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username']; // store in session
            $sql = "UPDATE user SET logindate=NOW() WHERE username='" .mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."'";
            mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in SQL: ".mysql_error());
        } else {
            // Invalid login
            echo header('Location: loginerror.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
} else {
    // No direct entry
    echo header('Location: loginerror.php');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: is it being sent via $POST or via $_SESSION - i see you started the session, yet reference username as $_POST

Comment: forgot to execute it. its fixed now